# Auto start After Install

Tags: electron

We have a Installer application Extension .Debian, I want to Start my application after install is this possible on Linux OS, on Electron Installer.

Comment: Please provided OS & release details.   An extension is just part of the *filename* and doesn't actually tell you anything (*giving us humans a huge clue, but it may be inaccurate*), you should ask the system what type of file it is using `file` etc.

Comment: Sure, it's probably *possible* depending upon which Linux OS you installed.